Find all ordered triples of primes $(p,q,r)$ such that $p\mid q^r+1, q\mid r^p+1, r\mid p^q+1$
Find all ordered triples of primes $(p,q,r)$ such that $p\mid q^r+1, q\mid r^p+1, r\mid p^q+1$
My Attempt:
Multiplying the three relationships gives:
$$pqr\mid(q^r+1)(r^p+1)(p^q+1) = q^r r^p p^q + q^r r^p + q^r p^q + r^p p^q + q^r + r^p + p^q + 1$$
Hence
$$pqr\mid q^r r^p + q^r p^q + r^p p^q + q^r + r^p + p^q + 1$$
but I'm not sure where else I can go.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is problem 3 from USA TST 2003, with solutions available on the net (and likely here too).
